# mySQL Access Denied Error After New User Created

Tags: php, mysql

I made some projects with using mysql and there was no problem. Today my friend show me how to create user in mysql by :

```
Create database cc;
use cc
CREATE USER 'testing'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
GRANT ALL ON cc.* TO 'testing'@'localhost';
```

Now I tried to use my project but I got following error :

```
Connection failed: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'login'
```

I deleted previously created user :

```
drop user 'testing'@'localhost';
```

I managed to delete that user, I checked user with :

```
select User from mysql.user;
```

testing account was gone but now I have 3 root accounts, I didn't understand why. Since I deleted that "testing" account, I tried my project again and I got the same error. Why I can't use default `'root'` account anymore?

EDIT :

Error part of php code :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "login";


// Error is in following line
$conn = mysqli_connect ( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
```

I also tried this :

```
GRANT ALL ON login.* TO 'root'@'localhost';

show grants;
```

Result is :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON login.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
```

It seems like 'root' has access to everything. Why am I getting error?

EDIT 2:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "login";
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect ( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
// Check connection
if (! $conn) {
    die ( "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error () );
}
```

Comment: You only granted permissions to the cc database, but you are trying to access database 'login'.

Comment: @ChipDean I deleted that user, I am using default root account in my project. I checked grants and root user has all grants localhost.

Comment: @Dosher can you copy and paste the error you are now receiving while using the root login?

Comment: @Muggles Connection failed: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'login'. It is weird that it says user "@'... it doesn't show a user name.

Comment: @Dosher try $conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'login'); and see if there is still an error?

Comment: @Muggles it worked but why? I did the exact same thing while defining variables before.

Comment: @Dosher Can you paste more of the code? Is the username variable assigned right before the connection? It appears that when called, it is of a null value.

Comment: @Muggles I noticed something, I used $username variable 2 times, before connection I assigned username to another variable. Is this the problem?

Comment: @Dosher it could be, if possible, could you edit your original question with more of the code including the two times you've used the $username variable.

Answer (score -1):

Your over riding the previously set $username variable with the $_POST['username'] data which appears to be empty. So mysqli_connect attempts to connect to the database with a blank username.

To correct this, rename the $username variable to something else which doesn't conflict.

Example:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "login";
$username_post = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect ( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
// Check connection
if (! $conn) {
     die ( "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error () ); 
}
```